# How to remove/delete (not reset or modify) response headers in hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Able to modify the response headers with `onPreHandler/onPostHandler` extention in hapi js. But not able to delete the key, value pair entirely. How to `delete/remove` response headers without setting it's value to `null` or `undefied`.

```js
server.ext("onPreResponse", async (request, h) => {
    if (request.response.isBoom) {
      request.response.output.headers["server"] = "";
      request.response.output.headers["x-powered-by"] = "";
    } else {
      if (request.response && request.response.headers) {
        request.response.header("server", "");
        request.response.header("x-powered-by", "");
      }
    }
    return h.continue;
});
```

Comment: please include the MWE code of what you have done so far.

Comment: please check the answer and let me know if any issue thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`request.response.output.headers`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/74d6b52bac3f8d159b12ba7eb6d4d4d1bd8e361e/lib/response.js#L38) & [`request.response.header`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/74d6b52bac3f8d159b12ba7eb6d4d4d1bd8e361e/lib/response.js#L38) are of `{}` you can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator to delete the key

```js
delete request.response.output.headers["server"];
delete request.response.output.headers["x-powered-by"];
```

Or

```js
delete request.response.headers["server"];
delete request.response.headers["x-powered-by"];
```

**Code:**

```
server.ext("onPreResponse", async (request, h) => {
    if (request.response.isBoom && request.response.output && request.response.output.headers) {
      delete request.response.output.headers["server"];
      delete request.response.output.headers["x-powered-by"];
    }
    else if (request.response && request.response.headers) {
        delete request.response.header["server"];
        delete request.response.header["x-powered-by"];
    }
    return h.continue;
});
```